# Execution of Struts basic application getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, xml, struts2

I'm new to struts framework. So seeking some online tutorials and tried to develop a very basic application. But I'm unable to run it properly

> after clicking button action method "execute()" was unable to locate
>   by container.

I am not getting what I'm missing.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SampleApplication</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list> 
  <filter>
   <filter-name>sample</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class> 
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>sample</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sample Struts Application</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="invoke">
<s:textfield name="name" label="UserName"></s:textfield><br>
<s:password name="password" label="Password"></s:password><br>
<s:submit value="GO"></s:submit>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default"><action name="invoke" class="com.techm.SampleStruts" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/Success.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package></struts>
```

SampleStruts.java

```
    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class SampleStruts extends ActionSupport{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String name, password;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }   
    public String execute()
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Jars used are :

> commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
>   freemarker-2.3.8.jar
>   ognl-2.6.11.jar
>   servlet-api-2.5.jar
>   struts2-core-2.0.11.jar
>   StrutsInterceptors.rar
>   xwork-2.0.4.jar

**Stack trace :**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.techm.SampleStruts.execute()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.getActionMethod(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:41)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
```

Comment: Clean, re-build, re-deploy.

Comment: Turn on trace level.

Comment: Upgrade to `2.3.28.1 ` , change the FilterDispatcher with the StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter, enjoy

Comment: Don't mess up different versions, if you want to know a version of Struts http://stackoverflow.com/q/35985333/573032

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution is that , after adding *.action* to the action value.

it is working fine.

```
<s:form action="invoke.action">
<s:textfield name="name" label="UserName"></s:textfield><br>
<s:password name="password" label="Password"></s:password><br>
<s:submit value="GO"></s:submit>
```