# Execute method is not invoking after first successful validation in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

LoginAction.java

```
public void validate() {
        System.out.println("Validate method....!!!");
        System.out.println("Username....::"+this.username);
        System.out.println("password....::"+this.password);
        if (!username.equals("admin") || !password.equals("admin123")) {

            System.out.println("Action Error added....");
        this.addFieldError(username, "Username /Password are invalid. Try again.");

        }
    }

    public String execute() 
    {
        System.out.println("Execute method..");
        return "success";
    }
```

Login.jsp

```
<s:form action="login.action">
 <s:fielderror cssStyle="color:red"/> 
  <s:textfield name="username" label="Username"/>
    <s:password name="password" label="Password"/>
    <s:submit value="Go"/>
</s:form>
```

When i run the application for first time, Login page will display. there if i give username and password as "admin" & "admin123" it will navigate to success page. if i come back to login page and if give wrong username or password it will validate and throws the error. up to here it is fine but again if i give correct username and password it should navigate to success page but after validate method , it is not executing execute method(), I am not getting what is the problem .It is Struts2 based application. please help me out.

Console logs :

```
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'login.action' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Validate method....!!!
Username....::admin
password....::admin123
Execute method..
Validate method....!!!
Username....::admin
23 May, 2016 4:42:59 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'login.action' in namespace: '/'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
password....::dfsdfsdf
Action Error added....
23 May, 2016 4:42:59 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
WARNING: No configuration found for the specified action: 'login.action' in namespace: '/'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
Validate method....!!!
Username....::admin
password....::admin123
23 May, 2016 4:43:06 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
```

Comment: `login.action` should be `login` in `<s:form>`.

Comment: if i remove .action it was not working for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209563/execution-of-struts-basic-application-getting-java-lang-nosuchmethodexception was my one of the problem earlier

Comment: Download a clean copy of Struts2 libraries and use them.

Comment: You'll need to show your configuration for the actions in question. You should definitely *not* need the `.action` extension in the form, however, which leads me to believe there's a configuration issue.

Comment: Also why do you print two times the *validate* execution with an *execute* in the middle ? Are you using PRG (redirectAction) ? Show your struts config